# Use deno to create windows network drive (using windows dll)

Tags: windows, dll, deno, network-drive

I want to rewrite an old `.bat` program into Deno compiled app.

I know how to handle most things, but I do struggle with creating network drives. Previously I used code like this:

```
cmdkey /add:PCName /user:user /pass:********
net use S: \\PCNam\path /persistent:yes /user:user ********
```

I looked for some libraries to use windows `dll` to do it properly this time, but I have no experience with Windows libraries or C in general.

Would someone point me to how to find the correct dll for the job and some simplified example on how to [provide the correct parameters to it](https://deno.land/x/win32@0.1.1/user32/dll.ts)?

---

Deno is able to [use provided `.dll` files as follow](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/ffi_api): (example from [win32 deno lib](https://deno.land/x/win32@0.1.1/user32/dll.ts))

```
const dll = Deno.dlopen("user32.dll", {
  MessageBoxW: {
    parameters: ["pointer", "pointer", "pointer", "u64"],
    result: "i32",
  },
});

dll.symbols.MessageBoxW(...);
```

Comment: So you need to write *C* code? Or in other languages? I am not familiar with your setup (*Deno*).

Comment: See the [subprocess](https://deno.land/manual/examples/subprocess) and [FFI](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/ffi_api) APIs.

Comment: @CristiFati Deno is nodeJS alternative that uses Typescript (Javascript superset). I do not need so much code, as information on what windows dll are available out of the box and what they do. Specifically, I look for 3: networking (set windows network drive), licence keys (I would love to get used windows key along with office key), HW info (get CPU name and GPU name and RAM size)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a